# Sql Server Express failed to generate user instance

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-express, user-instance

I am using `Visual Studio 2010/c#` and created an application where I am trying to access  as a data source,a database which I created in `SQLSERVER Express` (via management studio).

I have several instances from previous installs which I remove -

SQL COnfiguration manager just shows 1 instance SQLEXPRESS which got installed as a named instance "mymachine/sqlexpress".

Named pipes, TCP/IP and remote clients are all enabled.

I am running under windows 7 64 bit and both the dev environment and sql are in the same PC.

When I try and configure the connection I go to the physical path where the file resides, add it but the test connection button fails with the msg `failed to generate a user instance of sql server, only an integrated connection can generate an user instance`

The solutions I found don't seem to apply.

User Instance is already enabled (set to 1) and I could not find any path to remove "old instances" there is only 1 path leading to the currently installed Instance.

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio SQL Server database through IIS7,
they use `default asp.net` database.

Following might help,

- Open IIS manager.
- create a `new application pool` instead of using default application pool and keep your   database in that.
- Go to sql configuration manager > go to properties.
- Select `local system` instead of built in system.
- In the default browser option, Delete all the other files and paste your .asmx file.
- See in actions. If anything is disabled, enable it.

Hope it helps. :)